# Bash Move file and rename with incrementing extension

Tags: bash, unix, rename, move, increment

I have to write a Bash script that will look to see if a file exists and move the file to a specific directory, then rename the file with an extension of .1 or .2 etc if .1 already exists.  I feel like I have a good start on it but it's not recognizing the directory even though I can enter mv file destination directly and it works.  Where am I going wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
DESTINATION="~hbrown31/homework"
FILE=$1
if [ -e "$FILE" ]
 then
  for $FILE in 'ls|sort -g -r'
   do
    echo "File is being moved and renamed"
    NEWFILE="$DESTINATION""$FILE""."
    mv "$FILE" "$(NEWFILE + 1)"
   fi
 else
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: You probably need a final `/` on DESTINATION, or use "$DESTINATION/$FILE"

Comment: Also, $DESTINATION$FILE is probably not an integer, so what does it mean to increment it?

Comment: Correct.  I was missing the final / in the destination path.  When I move the file I have to add .number to the end of the file name.  If .1 already exists then I have to make it .2

Comment: Are you sure you need the tilde prefix in `DESTINATION` to be quoted? I guess you want: `DESTINATION=~hbrown31/"homework"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want (I don't understand the 'ls|sort', but I think you are looking for something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST=~hbrown31/homework  # Do not quote or the ~ will not be expanded

move() {
  suffix=0
  file="$DEST/$1"
  while test -e "$file"; do
    file="$DEST/$1.$((++suffix))"
  done
  mv -v "$1" "$file"
}

for x; do move "$x"; done
```

Note that some versions of `mv` do support options such as `-b` and `--backup` that may actually do most of the work for you.

Comment: `: $((suffix += 1 ))` is cute but `((suffix+=1))` or even `((++suffix))` is enough `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I like that the correct form of increment is used.

Comment: Suffix += 1 is more expressive.  It states what is being done rather than relying on a side-effect.  Using the post-increment would be appropriate if it were written as a one-liner: `file="$DEST/$1.$((++suffix))`